# Changing the XLim in a cfit plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have trouble changing the x-range (XLim) in plots of curve-fit objects.

**Preparing a Minimal Example**

Let's define noisy data and fit a function to it, using `fit` from the curve fitting toolbox.

```
xdata = (0:0.1:1)'; 
noise = 0.1*randn(size(xdata));
ydata = xdata.^2 + noise;
f = fittype('a*x.^2 + b'); 
fit1 = fit(xdata, ydata, f, 'StartPoint', [1,1]);
```

`fit1` is now a cfit object and we can plot it using its (overloaded) `plot` method:

```
plot(fit1, xdata, ydata)
```

**The Problem**

When we now change the XLim of the plot using `set(gca, 'XLim', [0,2])`, the plot updates but the fit curve is not extended. The documentation [suggests](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/curvefit/plot.html) that you can do that automagically from within the `plot` command, but for it does not work for me:

```
plot(fit1, xdata, ydata, 'XLim', [0, 1])

-> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

-> Error in cfit/plot (line 228)
->   handles = plot(xpoints(~outliers),ypoints(~outliers),S2,...
```

If I use `cftool` for the fit (a GUI wrapper for `fit`), I can enter XLim under `Tools->Axes Limits`. The fit function is then displayed for the whole range. How can I do this programmatically?

I am aware that you can evaluate the fit function for a given range, but when you have to do that for confidence intervals and several fits, this becomes tedious. I am looking for an easier way, and I think I am just uing the `plot` command wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says that when you plot a fit object, it will extrapolate to the current axis limits. It does not redraw the line after you change the plot limits. Further, it appears that when you overload *plot* it plots the fitdata as the same length as the xdata/ydata. To accomplish your goal, you could do

```
figure; hold on
plot(xdata,ydata,'.')
ext_xdata = 0:0.1:2;
plot(ext_xdata,fit1.a*ext_xdata.^2 + fit1.b,'r')
```

But you alluded that the above solution is undesirable for you because of complications of your application. An alternative approach is

```
figure; hold on
plot(xdata,ydata,'.')
set(gca,'xlim',[0, 2]);
plot(fit1)
```

This isn't a one line solution like what you seem to be looking for, but it removes the need to specify a new xrange.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I can replace your last line with `plot(fit1,'predobs', 0.95)` and get the desired graph. It's four lines instead of one, but it's a lot better than the evaluating the fit, the lower bound, the upper bound, and then plot everything manually.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Maybe a guru will still come along with a better approach

Answer (score 0):

The function `plot` that you use to plot a `fit` object actually overloads the standard `plot` function. If you try to set a breakpoint if error (`dbstop error`), you would see that the actual matlab `plot` function is called inside the function plotting a fit object. The syntax is then not exactly the same which means that you need to call either `xlim([minLim,maxLim]);` after you have plotted the function

```
plot(fit1,xdata, ydata);
xlim([minLim,maxLim]);
```

I am not sure why this happens since in [matlabs documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/plot.html) they actually state that it should work. This may be a bug which should be reported.

Comment: I reported the bug - let's hope they fix the documentation - or better, the function itself!